# How to get recommendations on the webpage

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Consider this page:

```
https://www.michaelkors.com/anorak-rainbow-swimsuit-belt-bag-the-michael-tote-dylan-sneaker/_/L-MSTR101163
```

I asked a question here on Stackoverflow a few days back and it was recommended that in order to scrape recommendations I should look into scrapy-splash. With splash, I am able to scrape most of the JS,however, I am stuck at scraping recommendations at the bottom of page. This is what I have tried so far:

```
recommendations = response.xpath("//div[@class ='you-may-also-like-section']/a/@href").getall()
```

This returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this selector:

`response.css('div.you-may-also-like-section div.product-tile-container a::attr(href)').extract()`

Also, you can try to set wait time in Splash browser.

But if you check Browser -> Network -> XHR, you will find this request https://api.rfksrv.com/search-rec/263221008/3
Everything that you should do is to make a request like that, but with your data, that was taken from a source page. I would recommend this way

in curl it looks so:

```
curl 'https://api.rfksrv.com/search-rec/263221008/3' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Referer: https://www.michaelkors.com/anorak-rainbow-swimsuit-belt-bag-the-michael-tote-dylan-sneaker/_/L-MSTR101163' -H 'Origin: https://www.michaelkors.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36' -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJyZWdpb24iOiJ1cy1lYXN0LTEiLCJzdWIiOiJhcGlLZXkvN255c1NhcnEiLCJzY29wZSI6eyIyNjMyMjEwMDgiOlsidzZndDQ0OHh1ZyJdfSwic3RhZ2UiOiJwcm9kIiwianRpIjoiNGI1M2MyOTItZDA4Ny00OGExLTkzYTctN2M5MTUzYjM2YWVmIiwiaWF0IjoxNTYzOTM2Nzk5LCJleHAiOjE1NjQwMjM3OTl9.UDqzF9cZHJ7KkCnrChvAV6vupP-gs6Bplv462rGII98' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data '{"data":{"batch":[{"widget":{"rfkid":"pdp1"}},{"widget":{"rfkid":"pdp2"}},{"widget":{"rfkid":"pdp_edt"}}],"context":{"page":{"uri":"/anorak-rainbow-swimsuit-belt-bag-the-michael-tote-dylan-sneaker/_/L-MSTR101163","sku":["126295789","314419197","287779605","287780826","321049671","512500966"],"locale_country":"us","locale_language":"en"},"user":{"uuid":"263221008-ox-ap-4u-1p-vws74v0y7idt0l5q27j4-1563955671571"}},"n_item":12,"content":{},"appearance":{}}}' --compressed
```

Comment: And the curl says bad or illegal request

Comment: for me curl works, maybe there are some location cookies. You can copy curl from your browser